# My subscriber's onNext and onComplete functions do not run when I call onNext within my FlowableOnSubscribe class

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

In an Android project that uses RxJava 2, I create a `Flowable` like this in the `onCreate` of my initial activity:

```
Flowable.create(new MyFlowableOnSubscribe1(), BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .doOnComplete(new MyAction())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new MySubscriber());
```

The implementation of the FlowableOnSubscribe is:

```
public class MyFlowableOnSubscribe1 implements FlowableOnSubscribe<String> {
    public static final String TAG = "XX MyFlOnSub1";

    @Override
    public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<String> emitter) {
        Log.i(TAG, "subscribe");

        emitter.onNext("hello");
        emitter.onComplete();
    }
}
```

This is the subscriber implementation:

```
public class MySubscriber implements Subscriber<String> {
    public static final String TAG = "XX MySubscriber";

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSubscribe");
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onComplete");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onError");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNext: " + s);
    }
}
```

And the action implementation is:

```
public class MyAction implements Action {
    public static final String TAG = "XX MyAction";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "run");
    }
}
```

In my output, I'm expecting to a log statement from `onNext`, but I don't see one. Instead, this is my entire output:

```
02-23 17:56:31.334 24176-24176/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MySubscriber: onSubscribe
02-23 17:56:31.334 24176-24219/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MyFlOnSub1: subscribe
02-23 17:56:31.334 24176-24219/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MyAction: run
```

This indicates that `onNext` never runs, and `onComplete` doesn't even run either. But `MyAction` runs successfully.

Here's what happens when I comment out the call to `onNext`:

```
02-23 17:58:31.572 24176-24176/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MySubscriber: onSubscribe
02-23 17:58:31.572 24176-26715/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MyFlOnSub1: subscribe
02-23 17:58:31.572 24176-26715/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MyAction: run
02-23 17:58:31.652 24176-24176/com.ebelinski.rxjavaexperimentproject I/XX MySubscriber: onComplete
```

In this case `onNext` of course doesn't run, but at least `onComplete` runs.

I expected that I would see `onComplete` run in both cases, and `onNext` run when I call `emitter.onNext`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to manually issue a request otherwise no data will be emitted when extending `Subscriber` directly:

```
@Override
public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onSubscribe");
    s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Alternatively, you could extend `DisposableSubscriber` or `ResourceSubscriber`.

Comment: That seems to be my problem. When I switched from using RxJava 1's `Observer` to RxJava 2's `Subscriber`, I didn't know I had to call request on the `Subscription` to actually get events. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing it? Is it possible your main thread exits before the Observable has a chance to emit the result because you are using `Schedulers.IO` for the subscribe thread. Also, your `observeOn` will not do anything as it is only used for further downstream operators.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to by further downstream operators for `observeOn`. I have been testing this by running the Android application on a tablet and viewing the output in logcat in the Android Monitor. I guess I'm not very familiar with Android threads. I tried using `Schedulers.io()` for both `observeOn` and `subscribeOn`, with no change. Setting `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` for both also had no effect.