# Manually trigger a RxJava combinelatest flowable

Tags: android, rx-java2, combinelatest

So i have a scenario in which i want to combine the newest results of two flowables and do something with it.

```
Flowable.combineLatest(
                info,
                list,
                BiFunction  {  ... }
        )
```

In certain conditions, i need to be able to get the the results again, and do some different stuff from before. So i could manually store the results of combinelatest somewhere, and then just reuse them but i was thinking, maybe there is a way to add a third flowable, and trigger onNext manually so the results are propagated again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to keeping the computed value around for later use. You can create a `BehaviorSubject` that acts as an intermediate variable, that when defined will have the computed value, or you can `publish()` the observable so that newer subscribers will get the most recent results.

BehaviorSubject intermediateResult = BehaviorSubject.create();

```
Flowable.combineLatest(info, list, ...)
  .subscribe( intermediateResult );
```

Alternatively,

```
Observable<Type> intermediateResult = Flowable.combineLatest(info, list, ...)
  .replay(1)
  .publish();
```

In either case, subscribing to `intermediateResult` will get the most recent computed value, if it is present.

Edit: make the function selectable on the fly:

```
Observable<FunctionSelector> fnSelector;

Observable<Type> intermediateResult = 
  Flowable.combineLatest(info, list, fnSelector, 
     (information, listToUse, selector) -> 
       getFunction(selector).apply(information, listToUse))
  .replay(1)
  .publish(1);
```

Comment: i dont want a cache. i need to be able to, when desired, get the COMBINED result of both flowables. the BiFunction is affected by an external variable

Comment: If you need to change the function, then you might want to tie the external variable to an observable, and have  that as input to the chain. I'll modify my answer shortly.

Comment: Would create a third flowable like this work:? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428472/my-subscribers-onnext-and-oncomplete-functions-do-not-run-when-i-call-onnext-wi @BobDalgleish

Comment: You really don't need to create an observable like that. Simply use a `BehaviorSubject` with an initial, sensible value, and update it by calling `onNext()`.